# Efficient Way to Obtain Date by Subtracting Dynamically Configured Time Unit

Tags: java

I have scheduled Jobs which read an "eligibility interval" to scan data which is sufficiently old, based on configurable parameters. The "old" criteria is proposed as a Value and a Java 7 Calendar Unit. Example:

```
job1.cron=0 10 6 * * *
job1.eligibleinterval.value=5
job1.eligibleinterval.unit=Calendar.DAY   # Job 1's Eligible Data is 5 days old

job2.cron=0 10 6 * * *
job2.eligibleinterval.value=1
job2.eligibleinterval.unit=Calendar.MONTH   # Job 2's Eligible Data is 1 month old
```

Ideally, supported units should include `Minutes, Hours, Days, Months, Years` (perhaps not `Seconds`).

In the code, it's necessary to calculate the cutoff date as follows (this is the `DAY` version hard-coded):

```
// This hard-codes DAYS
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now().minusDays(
   Long.parseLong(poperties.getProperty("job1.eligibleinterval.value")));
```

My question is, is there a good design solution (perhaps in Java 8) to subtract a dynamically provided Time Unit in Java 8 to avoid the `If/Else` decision trees for different units? Is there a more elegant solution than `minusDays`, `minusMonths`? (By the way, there's no quick method for `minusMinutes` or `minusHours`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the overload of [`LocalDate.minus()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#minus-long-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) that takes a `TemporalUnit`
:

```
long amount = Long.parseLong(properties.getProperty("job1.eligibleinterval.value"));
TemporalUnit unit = ChronoUnit.valueOf(properties.getProperty("job1.eligibleinterval.unit"));

LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now().minus(amount, unit);
```

This solution requires that your configuration file has the time units declared to conform with the constants in the [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) enum.

Comment: thanks, just one typo here: `ChronoUnit` with an "H"